# Git Syncing in Visual Studio returns URI formats are not supported

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to sync a solution in Visual Studio 2013.  All was working fine, yet lately I get the error "URI formats are not supported".  I am somewhat lost as in all my searches I have not been able to pin point what went wrong or what needs to be fixed/changed.

Thank you for any assistance in this matter.

Regards
Godfrey

**ADDENDUM:**

**I resolved this by simply closing the solution and syncing.  I do not need to change branches.**

Comment: I just had the same error after upgrading to VS2013 Update 2. Someone has already opened a ticket with MS (maybe you did?). https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/873510/visual-studio-2013-update-2-git-uri-formats-are-not-supported

Comment: I think this is a sort of catch-all exception, with misleading text, as the precise cause seems to vary, from what I found on google.

We have it on one machine only; others work fine. That one machine can successfully synch other solutions, but not one specific one. It can push, but pull (and synch) both fail. The work around is to use Tortoise Git to pull.

We re-installed that machine from the bare metal to try to fix this, but that didn't work. MS claim they know about the issue and have a fix in the pipe..

Comment: Closing the solution did not work for me.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when switching GIT branches in VS2013 Update2.  To get around the error, I first closed the solution and then switched branches. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a pull.

### Option 1:

---

Closing and reopening the solution did not help me.  (Visual Studio 2013 Update 2). 
What worked was to install **[Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/)**.

1. Run **Git Bash**.
2. Change directory to my project: `cd 'C:\Users\me\Source\Repos\project'`
3. Then type **`git pull origin master`**.  (Assuming your remote repo is origin and branch is master)

```sh
$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/me/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging README.md
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 README.md | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

### Option 2:

---

Use **[Source Tree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview)**, which is a pretty cool Windows Git client and use it to do a pull.

Comment: BTW, this happened to me because I made a commit on github and a commit on my local repo.  I had to do the pull (fetch and merge) from github first before doing the push.

Comment: And it happened to me again.  I really don't like this solution, but it does work.